# fabric.min.js:3 Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported

Tags: javascript, php, api, drive

I am using google drive API to fetch drive images on site.
But when I try to load google drive image on canvas it shows error
"fabric.min.js:3 Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.".

I have tried to make  crossOrigin: 'Anonymous' in fabric.Image.fromURL.
But IN this case I can not fetch src of image.It shoes error below

Redirect at origin 'https://docs.google.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost.mystore.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Here is the my some of code.

```
function initAuth() {
  gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
  gapi.auth2.init({
      client_id: clientId,
      scope: scopes
  }).then(function () {
    loadDriveApi();
  });
}
function loadDriveApi() {
  gapi.client.load('drive', 'v3', listFiles);
}
function listFiles() {
  var request = gapi.client.drive.files.list({
        'pageSize' : 10,
        'fields': "nextPageToken, files(id, name,mimeType,webContentLink,thumbnailLink)"
      });

}
```